# Moving mesh from the scene in Object3D and back

Tags: three.js

Aim is to make the transformation with the group of meshes relative to some reference point.

Part of the solution I found is to put the necessary meshes in Object3D, do the conversion on Object3D, and then get my meshes in the scene as they looks in the converted Object3D.
Perhaps, after adding back the mesh to the scene to get the position and rotation of worldMatrix?

And if I do the following:

```
scene.remove(mesh);
obj3d.add(mesh);

// make conversion 

obj3d.remove(mesh);
scene.add(mesh);
```

What happens with the mesh? His geometry still remains at the same location on the video card and all other data in RAM?

Comment: Good question, especially with a lot of meshes or sprites, like a shooting or repeating animation like falling raindrops

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397857/way-to-handle-multple-object-as-a-single-one-in-thee-js/28401692#28401692

Comment: Thank you, but it does not answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching and detaching objects from and to the scene requires a little more than that. Before you remove the object from one reference point to another, you have to apply the parents matrix world to the object (if you want it to be in the same wolrd position as before). Before you add the object to a another reference point, you have to apply the new parents **inverse** matrix world first (if you want it to be in the same world position as before)

If this sounds complicated, don't worry.

fortunatly there is helper functions for this in the THREEjs library.

The function are referenced here 
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/SceneUtils

and can be used by calling

```
THREE.sceneutils.attach (child, scene, parent);
```

and

```
THREE.sceneutils.detach (child, parent, scene);
```

mind the order of the arguments.

```
THREE.sceneutils.attach (mesh, scene, obj3d); //adds mesh as child to obj3d
                                              //while mentaining its position

// make conversion

THREE.sceneutils.detach (mesh, obj3d, scene); //adds mesh as child to scene
                                              //while maintaining its position
```

also, check the source code of those functions if you are intrested in how it is done.

hope that answers your question

editted the answer because i got thing confused myself